# CardView CheckBox Empty Space

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, cardview

I am making a very simple Android app using Kotlin that has a checkbox list. The checkbox only works when I click on the box itself or the text beside it. My question is: How do I check the boxes by clicking on the empty spaces next to the texts?

[How to check boxes by clicking the empty space?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZrfr.png)

Comment: Use a `match_parent` size for the CheckBox

Comment: Oh, duh. I feel so dumb for not thinking to do that lol thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Give your CardView an `id` attribute in your XML.

Then you can do something like this in your Activity or Fragment:

```kotlin
findViewById<CardView>(R.id.card_view).setOnClickListener {
    val checkBox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkbox)
    checkBox.isChecked = !checkBox.isChecked
}
```